# Crear JSON a partir de otro JSON

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, array

Necesito ayuda para la creación de JSON nuevo a parir de un JSON que recibo por una url.
Por poner un ejemplo de una url `http:/www.urldeejemplo.com` recibo unos datos:

```
[{"Nombre":"Jose","apellido":"perez"},{"Nombre":"Luis","apellido":"hernández"}]
```

Necesito crear un nuevo JSON a partir de este pero con dos campos más, uno que sería la concatenación de nombre y apellidos y otro al que añadir una parte fija para que quedase algo así:

```
[{"Nombre":"Jose","apellido":"Perez","Datos_completos":"Jose_Perez","posicion":"Jose_empleado"},{"Nombre":"Luis","apellido":"hernández", "datos_completos":"Luis_hernández", "posicion":"Luis_empleado"}]
```

El campo de posición siempre será el Nombre + _empleado.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Que has probado hasta ahora? Ten en cuenta que lo que tienes es un listado de objetos, y el primer elemento de ese listado tiene los datos que necesitas. Así que en principio con iterar por el listado y a cada elemento añadirle lo que te interesa lo tienes...

Comment: Tu JSON inicial tiene elementos con claves repetidas y no es válido, en todo caso, sería: `[{"Nombre":"Jose","apellido":"perez"}, {"Nombre":"Luis","apellido":"hernández"}]`, con llaves para separar elementos.

Comment: Esos ejemplos de JSON que tienes, enrealidad son JSON imposibles, puedo afirmarlo al decir que las propiedades de tus dos JSON seran sobreescritas y combinadas al ultimo de sus valores, por lo cual tu objeto con propiedades repetidas no es posible, y el segundo tampoco (intenta asignar alguno de esos a una variable y luego imprimelo y veras aquello a lo que me refiero), ahora bien, eso de crear un tercer campo para tu objeto teniendo en cuenta los otros dos campos si que es posible.

Comment: Sin embargo deberas tener en cuenta que como se fusionan tus propiedades repetidas entonces siempre el JSON generado nunca podra contener toda tu informacion original, puesto que tus campos se fusionan (o mas bien se descartan los primeros y quedan los ultimos), debes replantear tu JSON, porque crear un JSON con propiedades repetidas genera este inconveniente.

Comment: Gracias y perdona Triby, no estaban los elementos separados. Acabo de editar la pregunta para arreglarlo. Ese json es el que recibo de otra parte para yo generar uno nuevo.

Comment: Lo haces con javascript puro o puedes usar typeScript??

Answer (score 1):

Debes replantear tu `JSON`, porque crear un `JSON` con propiedades repetidas genera el inconveniente de que luego al ser parseados (en este caso no es necesario parsear el JSON), los campos repetidos serán descartados en orden del primero al ultimo, es decir, si tienes esto:

```js
const json = {"nombre": "William", "nombre": "Luis", "nombre": "Julian"};
console.log(json);
```

Como podemos ver en el snippet, la ultima propiedad con el ultimo valor en ser agregada, son los "pares" de valores que "sobrevivirán".

Solucion a esto??, usar objetos diferentes en un array, por lo cual tu primer array de `JSON` pasa a ser este:

```js
const info = [{"Nombre":"Jose","apellido":"perez"},{"Nombre":"Luis","apellido":"hernández"}];
console.log(info);
```

Lo cual ahora si que es correcto y ademas no se sobreescriben las propiedades ni los valores.

Bien, dices que deseas crear un nuevo objeto apartir de propiedades existentes de otro, pero primero para ello **se debe crear una copia sin referencias de tu objeto original**, puesto que si intentamos usar el objeto original para crear otro, podremos sin querer sobreescribir las propiedades del `JSON` original, para poder crear un `JSON` sin referencias apartir de otro `JSON` usamos `Object.assign`, y luego iteramos con map para añadir las propiedades que deseas:

```js
const orgInfo = [{"Nombre":"Jose","apellido":"perez"},{"Nombre":"Luis","apellido":"hernández"}];

let extendedInfo = Object.assign([], orgInfo);
extendedInfo = extendedInfo.map(obj =>{
  obj.Datos_completos = `${obj.Nombre}_${obj.apellido}`;
  obj.posicion = `${obj.Nombre}_empleado`;
  return obj;
});

console.log(extendedInfo);
```

De esta manera hemos creado un objeto extendido sin referencias al original, el cual podremos usar sin problemas, y que ademas contiene nuevas propiedades, las propiedades `Datos_completos` y `pocision`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Riven!

Comment: De nada, recuerda que si mi respuesta te fue de ayuda, puedes darla como aceptada ;3